# Проблема с атрибутами класса Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

у меня есть класс

```
class RegistrationEventHandler:
    __REGISTER = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, registation_message, data):
        if registation_message.id not in cls.__REGISTER:
            cls.__REGISTER[registation_message.id] = data

    @classmethod
    def does_exist(cls, item) -> bool:
        return item in cls.__REGISTER
```

Когда я вызываю метод register и вписываю данные в словарь, через некоторое время когда я вызываю does_exist(), я получаю False и словарь является пустым в этот момент. NOTE: Данные из словаря не удаляются между вызовами, ключи верные, вывел словарь в консоль после записи и словарь содержит данные, вывел словарь после проверки does_exist() - словарь пустой, класс находится в отдельном файле и импортируется через from module_name import RegistrationEventHandler, вызовы методов register и does_exist осуществляются также в разных файлах скрипта.

Comment: Составьте [mcve], что где когда и как вы вызываете

Comment: @andreymal это код работающий с API, к сожалению я не смогу составить воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: В показанном вами коде проблема не воспроизводится, всё работает замечательно, словарь совсем не пустой https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooVdk.png

Comment: Да, что достаточно странно, так как у меня в одном файле вызывается функция (первая) что вызывает в свою очередь (вторую) функцию, внутри которой вызывается register() метод и после этого внутри (первой) функции словарь принтится пустым для этого класса

Comment: @andreymal помимо этого, вы запускали код в консоли, мой же случай осуществляется когда класс находится в отдельном файле, первый модуль вызывает функцию второго модуля где и вызываются методы класса, а после в первом модуле словарь этого класса пуст.

Comment: Если вы знаете условия, при которых проблема гарантированно воспроизводится, значит составьте [mcve]. Если нет — мы не телепаты и ничем помочь не сможем

Comment: @andreymal к сожалению, у меня не получилось воспроизвести это в других условиях, но я решил обойти проблему способом вызова методов класса из одного модуля (а не из двух), что повлияло на работу скрипта в лучшую сторону, в любом случае мне было бы интересно разобраться почему словарь становился пустым при работе с классом из разных файлов.